# My flex application seems blocked by china censorship

Tags: apache-flex, https, firewall, blocked

I devellop a Flex web application for customers all over the world. Since few weeks, we have been starting business in China.
Big problem, our distributor don't succeeded to load the web Application.
Effectively, our url seems blocked by china firewall. I tested it with this site : https://en.greatfire.org/.
I don't know where to start to be autorized in China. Do you know particular rules about https certificate (Go daddy certificate for us) or maybe about application using Flash player? Somebody was already confronted to this type of problem?

My url I try to load in China is : https://www.eco-visio.net/

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the certificate of your web-site.
Do you know any other websites that work fine with the certificate from Go daddy?

Comment: Thank for your answer, We have another url which hosting other applications with also a certificate from Go daddy. In China, this url (https://eco-public.com) seems work. I don't really know what can blocked. Nor can I access to my application by the IP adress of my server. But if I host my application on other Url, it work.